# Kion diri pri manĝaĵoj kiuj "malboniĝis"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Manĝaĵoj kiuj estas lasataj tro longe iĝas malsanigaj kaj malbonodoraj. Kiel oni nomas tiun procezon en Esperanto? Ĉu simple "ĝi malboniĝas"? Laŭ mi, tio ne estas tute klara. Ekzemple pano ĉiutage iĝas pli seka kaj do pli malbona, sed nur kiam ekkreskas verdaj/blankaj punktoj sur ĝi mi taksas ĝin vere malsaniga.

Comment: Nek vere respondo nek komento, sed eble utila rimaĵo pri malboniĝintaĵoj por la ĉiutaga uzo: "En okazo de dubo ĝi estas rubo", kp. la anglan "If in doubt, throw it out".

Comment: Ah, estas amuze ankaux lerni tiajn dirajxojn flanke je la strikta lernado de vortoj kaj gramatiko.

Comment: La reta PIV diras, ke ‘putri’ estas netransitiva, sed Benson, sub ‘spoil’, diras, ke ‘putri’ estas transitiva.

Answer (score 10):

Tio kompreneble dependas de la manĝaĵo.

Plej ĝenerale, manĝaĵoj **malfreŝiĝas**.

Pano **sekiĝas**, malfreŝiĝas, aŭ **ŝimas**.

Viando **putriĝas** (fariĝas putra; putras).

Fruktoj putriĝas (fariĝas putraj; putras).

Fiŝoj estas kiel gastoj - post tri tagoj ili **fetoras**.

Comment: Lingva atentigo: estas _putri_, ne _putriĝi_. La radiko en si jam enhavas la statŝanĝon.
Krom tio mi konsentas kun via respondo.

Comment: Fakte, vi pravas **sed efektive** ambaŭ eblas kaj troviĝas en tre diversaj verkoj (inkluzive nur ekzemple kaj la nova kaj la manova testamentoj). Mi redaktos mian respondon.

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm interesa demando ja estas tio ĉi. Mi ne certas ke tio ĉi estas la preciza aŭ sola respondo, sed mi dirus en tiu ĉi situacio "putri." Ekzemple, la pano ne estis manĝita dum tri tagoj kaj tiel ni *putrigis* ĝin.

Mi esperas ke tio helpis :3

Answer (score 0):

La **ŝimfunga** pano estas **putra**.

ŝimfungo = Malgranda filamenta fungo... kreskanta en kaj sur malseka organika materialo, ekz. nutraĵoj ordinare putriganta ilin... - ReVo

putri = Malkomponiĝi, p. p. organisma substanco - ReVo